# Update gridview from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to update a gridview using c# code behind. I typically use the SqlDataSource, but I need to capture the current user making the change and that doesn't seem to work. So I thought I would give it a try in the code behind.

**Here is the gridview:**

```
<asp:GridView
ID="gv_rvw_sub"
runat="server"
AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True"
DataSourceID="sdc_gv_rvw_sub"
CellPadding="4"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
EmptyDataText="There are no records to display."
OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_rvw_sub_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnRowUpdating="gv_rvw_sub_RowUpdating">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_id_pk" HeaderText="Submission" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_id_pk"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_by" HeaderText="Submitted By" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_by" ReadOnly="true"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list" HeaderText="Recipient" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_recip_list" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_dt" HeaderText="Date Submitted" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ReadOnly="true"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_due_dt" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_due_dt" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Review Status" HeaderText="Review Status" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_status_list">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList
ID="DropDownList1"
runat="server"
AutoPostBack="True"
DataSourceID="sdc_doc_rvw_sub_status_list"
DataTextField="rvw_status"
DataValueField="rvw_status_id_pk"
AppendDataBoundItems="true"
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("doc_rvw_sub_status_list") %>'>
<asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rvw_status") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Set By" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by">
<EditItemTemplate>
<%--<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("doc_rvw_sub_by") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>--%>
<asp:TextBox ID="status_set_by_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by") %>' ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set" HeaderText="Status Date" SortExpression="doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="doc_rvw_id_fk" HeaderText="Document ID" SortExpression="doc_rvw_id_fk" ReadOnly="true"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Here is the SqlDataSource:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
ID="sdc_gv_rvw_sub"
runat="server"
ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:idrfConnectionString %>"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_doc_rvw_sub] ([doc_rvw_sub_by], [doc_rvw_sub_recip_list], [doc_rvw_sub_dt], [doc_rvw_sub_status_list], [doc_rvw_id_fk]) VALUES (@doc_rvw_sub_by, @doc_rvw_sub_recip_list, @doc_rvw_sub_dt, @doc_rvw_sub_status_list, @doc_rvw_id_fk)"
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
SelectCommand="
SELECT [doc_rvw_sub_id_pk]
, [doc_rvw_sub_by]
, [doc_rvw_sub_recip_list]
, [doc_rvw_sub_dt]
, [doc_rvw_sub_status_list]
, tsl.rvw_status
, [doc_rvw_id_fk] 
, [doc_rvw_sub_due_dt]
, [doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by]
, [doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set]
FROM [tbl_doc_rvw_sub] 
LEFT JOIN tbl_status_list tsl 
ON tbl_doc_rvw_sub.doc_rvw_sub_status_list=tsl.rvw_status_id_pk 
WHERE ([doc_rvw_id_fk] = @doc_rvw_id_fk)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gv_doc_rvw" Name="doc_rvw_id_fk" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Here is the code behind:**

```
protected void gv_rvw_sub_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection idrf_cnxn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WDBSVCPRD01\\SVCDB;Initial Catalog=idrf;Integrated Security=True");
{
SqlCommand updt_sub_rvw_cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_doc_rvw_sub(doc_rvw_sub_status_list, doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by, doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set) WHERE (doc_rvw_sub_status_list=@doc_rvw_sub_status_list, doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by=@doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by, doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set=@doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set)", idrf_cnxn);
updt_sub_rvw_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_rvw_sub_status_list", gv_rvw_sub.FindControl("DropDownList1"));
updt_sub_rvw_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
updt_sub_rvw_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set", DateTime.Now.ToString());

idrf_cnxn.Open();
updt_sub_rvw_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
idrf_cnxn.Close();

if (IsPostBack)
{
gv_doc_rvw.DataBind();
}
}
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error - "Incorrect syntax near '('"

Where have I gone wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: this is where you would want to remove the `SQL` from the project and put it into a stored procedure, the error is telling you what is wrong.. so you need to look at the Insert statement or UpDate statement and check to see if the syntax is correct as well as proper spacing also look up proper syntax for an update statement

Comment: In Update statement `UPDATE tbl_doc_rvw_sub(doc_rvw_sub_status_list` can you not see ( in table name

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.   Thanks Neel.

Comment: here is basic `syntax for update statement`
`UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update statement syntax in SQL is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

I think your update statement should be

```
UPDATE tbl_doc_rvw_sub SET doc_rvw_sub_status_list=@doc_rvw_sub_status_list, doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by=@doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by, doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set=@doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set WHERE doc_rvw_sub_status_list=@doc_rvw_sub_status_list, doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by=@doc_rvw_sub_status_set_by, doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set=@doc_rvw_sub_status_dt_set
```